# Pre-Decrement Operator

Tags: c++, operators

My question is related to calling a function as well as decrement operator.
The answer for the following code is 
20 1
19 10
My question is that after "--m" the m should be 19 so it should send 19 and finally 19 should be print giving output 
19 1
19 10
but why is m not changing even though there is "--m"?

```
void f(int a, double b){cout<< a--<< '\t'<< b<< endl;}

int g(double x, int y){ return (x / ++y);}

int main()
{

int m = 20, n = 10;

f(m, g(--m, n));

cout<< m<< '\t'<< n << endl;

return 0;

}
```

Comment: The order of argument evaluation is not specified in C++.

Comment: Use a debugger and step through the code, watching the values of the variables as you do so. It's the best way to figure this sort of thing out,  and trying to step through foolishly written code like you have here is a valuable educational experience in itself.

Comment: This foolishly written code is something that was given in  a exam before, I already know the output but the output that is being displayed but is not matching my concept of --m. 
If you don't have the answer then please don't criticize the question
Thanks

Comment: @KenWhite in this case, the debugger will not help:  it may work in one way with one compiler, but produce different results with another compiler (or a future version of your compiler). So regardless the debugger, you can't count on this behavior and it should be avoided in production code.

Comment: @Christophe: Yes, I was hoping an attempt at debugging it would teach this poster the pitfalls of writing such code.

Comment: @KenWhite This is just a code to check the concept in exams. Anyways I got my answer thanks to you. 
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is unspecified behavior.  The C++ doesn't state the order of evaluation of parameters.

Comment: And different compilers *do* actually evaluate arguments in different order, so you *will* get different results with different compilers.